# Facebook Error 191 on canvas app using FB.ui() for the 'feed' dialog (worked before, stopped working last week)

Tags: dialog, feed, facebook-javascript-sdk, fb.ui

I'm having a sudden problem with FB.ui() for showing a feed dialog for a user to post content from my canvas app onto their facebook feed. This was working up until about a week ago, and we haven't deployed any new code to this.

```
FB.ui({
    "method":"feed",
    "name":"Your Horoscope for Today",
    "link":"http://apps.facebook.com/dhbdayscopetest/",
    "app_id":"213524052014025",
    "picture":"http://iota.tarot.com/fb/bday/images/signs/capricorn.png",
    "caption":"Capricorn",
    "description":"The time for romantic ideals and impulsive desires is passing quickly. In order to experience the best part of the day, you must do the work, make the...",
    "actions":[{
        "name":"Read More",
        "link":"http://apps.facebook.com/dhbdayscopetest/"
    }]
}, function(){ /* react */ });
```

I'm suddenly getting this response:

```
API Error Code: 191
API Error Description: The specified URL is not owned by the application
Error Message: redirect_uri is not owned by the application.
```

I've seen other questions whose answers say to make sure site url / canvas url / app domain all match, but they do and they're all set properly.

I can throw a redirect_uri to the FB.ui() call, which works to post the thing to the user's feed in this popup, but then the popup follows through after the post and loads my canvas page in the tiny little popup window. Before this started happening, the dialog box would just close after a successful post. This is the behavior I want, is there something I should be doing to get it?